# Can a Bot in a Google Hangout Room access Active Users

Tags: google-apps-script, bots, google-hangouts

My team is finding @all to be way too much - people are being notified when they're off, which is a non-starter for us. I've searched the AppScript documentation, and all i'm finding is how to reply to individuals.

What I want: The ability to detect users that are Active in Hangouts, and @mention each of them by calling a bot. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this feature doesn't exist in the Hangouts Chat API - specifically, the [spaces.members resource](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members) (is where I presume this would best fit under) & at all other resources.

I strongly recommend [filing a feature request on their Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047215), for now.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, at current there is no way using the Hangouts API to check the status of members that are in a chat group.*

#### Feature Request:

I'm from G Suite support. This is a feature that is available in other popular chat application APIs, and so I have taken the liberty of creating a feature request for this for you on Google's Issue Tracker. This Feature Request can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142371247), which you can give a star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people wish for this request.

#### References:

- [Hangouts Chat REST API Reference](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference)
- [Feature Request for this on Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142371247)